# Local version of jquery not referenced properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I was able to implement the jquery UI shake effect when I reference a CDN to host my *.js files but due to our network gateway restriction, I need to host the files on local server. 
When I change the src location, I receive the error:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

This works when jquery referenced like this client side:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I receive the "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" error when referenced like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
    Try

If pN1.Value.Trim Is String.Empty Or pN1.Value.Trim Is Nothing Then
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "shakePN1", "shakePN();", True)

  Exit Sub
End If

'More code after...
```

Client side function being called from server side:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function shakePatientName() {            
        /**
        * when button is clicked we call the effect jQuery UI plugin
        * we use the shake effect for one sec
        */
        $("#shaker").effect('shake', { times: 5 }, 800);         
    }


</script>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks for looking

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console to make sure that you're loading the jQuery libraries? Have you considered placing your script in a document ready handler?

Comment: You just can go to `Solutions Explorer->Scripts Folder` and just drag and drop your jquery file to the head in your `Site.Master` code view....

Comment: Paths don't support the `~/` syntax on the client side, so your scripts aren't referenced properly. Try just using `/`, you might also try passing in the site root from the server side (which will be handy if you decide to host it in a virtual application/directory.

Comment: @mason. It appears to be that. I removed the ~ and it has now worked.  Thanks to all for the information. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @EdSF This isn't Razor. This is Web Forms. Look at the button click handler.

Comment: @mason Arg...got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript paths don't support the `~/` syntax on the client side, so your scripts aren't referenced properly. Try just using `/`, you might also try passing in the site root from the server side (which will be handy if you decide to host it in a virtual application/directory.)